# isql не могу подключиться к oracle

Tags: oracle

Добрый день. не могу подключиться к oracle через isql.

```
[08004][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
   [mthbz]
Driver= ORACLE
DSN= mthbz
ServerName= mth
UserID= dan
Password= dan
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[ORACLE]
Description = Oracle ODBC Connection
Driver = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
Setup =
FileUsage =
```

/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
MTHBZ =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.98.10.20)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = mth)
    )
  )
```

env

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin
ODBCSYSINI=/etc
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin
```

Comment: `tnsping MTHBZ` что возвращает? Пробовали подключаться с sqlpus'а ?

Comment: sqlplus работает отлично. tnsping сейчас поставлю

Comment: Не нашёл нормального гайда как поставить tnsping

Comment: Он установлен. Надо просто в командной строке вбить `tnsping MTHBZ`. Я правильно понял, что подключение через sqlplus проходит корректно?

Comment: В ubuntu нет tnsping MTHBZ
tnsping: команда не найдена sqlplus работает отлично, нужен завести isql

Comment: tnspin должен быть в папках ораклового клиента. В папке bin

Comment: там 2 папки help и sdk в sdk admin demo и include в help ja us

Comment: У вас удается корректно подключиться через sqlplus используя tns. Например так `sqlplus <user>/<password>@MTHBZ` ?

Comment: Короче всё получается, после этого открывается строка
SQL>

Comment: А если в ODBC заменить `ServerName= mth` на `ServerName= MTHBZ` ?

Comment: Аааа завелось, спасибо

Comment: для дебага листнера лог находиться тут
```grep SERVICE_NAME= /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ora01/listener/alert/log.xml```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на основе комментариев
Необходимо исправить ODBC:

```
   [mthbz]
Driver= ORACLE
DSN= mthbz
ServerName= MTHBZ
UserID= user
Password= pass
```

В `ServerName` указывается алиас из `TNS`, а был указан `SERVICE_NAME`